# (をする) and (がする). Meanings and Uses

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, particle-が, particle-を

What does (をする) and (がする). Sometime ago I read on site something I dont remember, but I got confused because the use of 勉強がする, but I just knew the existence of 勉強をする. So actually Im pretty confused. Any help is appreciated

勉強をする and
勉強がする

復活をする and
復活がする

感情がする and
感情をする

Answer (score 6):

Here's the basic difference.

- `[noun] + をする`: common; means "do ～".
- `[noun] + がする`: relatively uncommon; means "there's a sense of ～", "feel ～".

> 勉強をする and 勉強がする
>   復活をする and 復活がする

勉強 here is a noun meaning 'study', and 復活 here is a noun meaning 'revival/resurrection'. So 勉強をする and 復活をする make sense, but 勉強がする/復活がする does not make sense. Examples:

- 日本語の勉強をする To study Japanese (literally, 'do a study of Japanese')
- 完全な復活をする To be back in full force (literally, 'do a complete revival')

> 感情がする and 感情をする

感情 is a noun meaning 'feeling/emotion'. Only 感情がする makes sense, although it's rare. Examples and similar expressions:

- 冷たい感情がする (rare) To feel chilliness
- 悪い予感がする To feel something bad is happening (literally, 'feel a bad foresight')
- 残念な気持ちがする To feel regret (literally, 'feel a regrettable feeling')
- ひどい臭いがする There is a terrible smell

Comment: Just one thing. Is をする more used than がする?, or what do you refer with common and uncommon?

Comment: I think the number of available expressions using "○○がする" is relatively small. It may look tricky at first glance, but it's worth learning.

Answer (score 0):

勉強がする and 復活がする don't make sense.

感情がする and 感情をする themselves make little sense but for example, なつかしい感情がした can be understood as 懐かしい感情を覚えた and 複雑な感情をしたロボット as "a robot who is equipped with complex emotion".